# Logfile redirection in Sidekiq 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, logging, redis, sidekiq

Below is my systemd sidekiq.service setup. I am trying to get my logs in my sidekiq.log file.

Current configuration:

- Sidekiq: **7.1.6**
- Redis: **7.2.2**
- Ubuntu: **18.04**

```
Type=simple
Environment="RAILS_ENV=staging"
WorkingDirectory=/home/workspace/rails/app
ExecStart=/home/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec sidekiq -C /home/workspace/rails/app/config/sidekiq.yml

ExecReload=/usr/bin/kill -TSTP $MAINPID

User=user
UMask=0002

Environment=MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2

RestartSec=1
Restart=on-failure

StandardOutput=file:/home/workspace/rails/app/log/sidekiq.log
StandardError=file:/home/workspace/rails/app/log/sidekiq.log

SyslogIdentifier=sidekiq
```

I can't see the logs reflecting in sidekiq.log. But if I change `StandardError` and `StandardOutput` to `syslog`, I can see the logs reflecting under syslog. I have restarted daemon and sidekiq as well after editing my systemd file.